# Failing to deploy a Django web app to AWS beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy A django app to beanstalk and I get some errors related to python and requirements.txt and I can't figure out what to do, Any help is appreciated.
here are the errors I get: (the logs are in pastebin bellow)

ERROR

```
[Instance: i-0e7826c4558b1d21a] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2022-04-28 15:13:52 UTC+0000
```

ERROR

```
Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
```

logs:
https://pastebin.com/g1uZLqur

here is my requirements.txt

```
Django==2.2.6
django-environ==0.4.5
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
django-paypal==1.0.0
https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/tarball/v2
git+https://github.com/nn3un/reportlab-mirror#egg=reportlab
boto3==1.4.4
django-storages==1.8
psycopg2
django-guardian
bokeh==1.4.0
django-ses==2.0.0
mock
```

Comment: What does your reqs.txt file look like?

Comment: Django==2.2.6
django-environ==0.4.5
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
django-paypal==1.0.0
https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/tarball/v2
git+https://github.com/nn3un/reportlab-mirror#egg=reportlab
boto3==1.4.4
django-storages==1.8
psycopg2
django-guardian
bokeh==1.4.0
django-ses==2.0.0
mock
@Daniel